# I cannot understand how Dart Editor evaluates expressions when consider that code is dead

Tags: dart, code-analysis, dart-editor

This source code generates a warning in Dart Editor. `Dead code`

1)

```
if(false) {
}
```

But this constant expressions that also evaluates to `false` does not generates a warning.

2)

```
if("hello" is int) {
}
```

3)

```
if(false || false) {
}
```

4)

```
if(false == true) {
}
```

5)

```
if(0 > 0) {
}
```

How Editor can help me in these cases?

You may consider that all my examples are not from real life.

But I also can consider that this code not from real life.

```dart
if(false) {
}
```

So, how support of only case #1 and lack of support of cases #2, #3, #4, #5 and all other possible can help me finding dead code in Dart Editor?

P.S.

Of course, this is a great feature of Dart Editor, and I do not want to downplay her usefulness, but I still want to know: "Is this possible to make it even more of the greatest that there was little more usefulness?".

Answer (score 3):

In general it's not possible to prove that code is "dead" because it would require running that code *at compile time* , and that code could have a huge run time or never terminate.

SO they have to draw a line somewhere and it looks like they have decided that simple true/false values will be used but nothing more complicated will be evaluated at compile time. You may question where they draw the line and argue that simple expressions could be usefully evaluated, but as it's impossible in general to prove that code is dead, they have to make a decision somewhere...

Comment: It all depends on the depth and completeness of analysis. If we analyze the expressions we can collect much more interesting. Also write evaluator of expressions under primitive values ​​not so hard. Also good tool (if it called analyzer) must analyze all code paths and evaluate all expressions (if this possible) . This called static single assignment form (SSA), use-definition chain (UD Chain) and live variable analysis (liveness analysis). I think that Dart Editor uses Data-flow analysis but I was wrong. "Simple true/false values" are not a no the same as control flow graph (CFG) analysis.

Comment: I am sorry but you really think that for performing good and complete analysis required as you say "running that code at compile time , and that code could have a huge run time or never terminate". Can you provide for me link to this kind of analysis ("run-code-at-compile-time-and-wait-a-huge-time-until-it-terminate-for-performing-good-analysis")?

Comment: Well you could call a function that always returns zero but isn't trivial to prove it does. For example what if you called a function that checked it an integer was a prime number and passed it a billion digit number. The answer is false so an if condition depending on it is "dead code" because it can never be called. But you don't know that without essentially spending almost infinite time proving that at compile time.

Comment: All that I wanted to say is that such a "useful" feature as this unique warning, I have never been met. This is for that the case, if you still do not understand what is the meaning.